# finding the value of a td in React

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I'm developing Test on React using enzyme, and I want to reach the value of this "td"

```
<td className="myCell" key={String(x) + String(y)}>{value}</td>
```

but using this code :

```
ArrayAreaComponent.find("td").first().render()
```

I recive:

```
initialize {
  '0': {
    type: 'tag',
    name: 'td',
    namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    attribs: [Object: null prototype] { class: 'myCell' },
    'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] { class: undefined },
    'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] { class: undefined },
    children: [ [Object] ],
    parent: null,
    prev: null,
    next: null,
    root: {
      type: 'root',
      name: 'root',
      namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
      attribs: [Object: null prototype] {},
      'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] {},
      'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] {},
      children: [Array],
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null
    }
  },
  options: {
    withDomLvl1: true,
    normalizeWhitespace: false,
    xml: false,
    decodeEntities: true
  },
  length: 1,
  _root: [Circular]
}
```

How can I extract the value from this object? and where can I find more information about this kind of object?

Comment: What value you need to extract?

Comment: the value inside the td tag

Comment: I think you misunderstand React. Don't get values from the DOM - you knew the value when you were rendering the element ("{value}"). Where did that come from? You might want to keep that in the state. Then, whenever it changes, React will update the screen. So don't try to read the value from the <td> element but instead keep it in your state and read it from there.

Comment: I would like to read it during the test, to be sure that it rendered correctly, as I posted under I founded a solution. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end I solved by using the function

```
wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<td>{value}</td>).toBeTruthy;
```